# How do I get grunt-init to warn only if the files I'm creating exist?

Tags: gruntjs

There are a number of examples for "warnOn" in the grunt docs:

```
exports.warnOn = 'grunt.js';        // Warn on a grunt.js file.
exports.warnOn = '*.js';            // Warn on any .js file.
exports.warnOn = '*';               // Warn on any non-dotfile or non-dotdir.
exports.warnOn = '.*';              // Warn on any dotfile or dotdir.
exports.warnOn = '{.*,*}';          // Warn on any file or dir (dot or non-dot).
exports.warnOn = '!*/**';           // Warn on any file (ignoring dirs).
exports.warnOn = '*.{png,gif,jpg}'; // Warn on any image file.
```

But I have only seen examples that warn you in advance of any questions being asked or answered in the prompt. What I want is to be warned only if the file(s) I'm creating already exist in the project (or in specified paths), after I fill in the answer. Something like:

```
**Please answer the following:**
Project name: example
```

Assuming that a file named "example" already exists, I want to be warned at that point, so that I can change the name to something else. I imagine it would be something like this:

```
warnOn = '{%= name %}';     // File being created already exists in project
```

But I don't know how to implement this so that it only warns after I enter a value.

Hopefully this makes sense, I'm happy to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, since the `warnOn` check is only done [before the prompt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init/blob/master/tasks/init.js#L69-L72).

However it's just Node.js, so you can easily implement the check yourself:

```
if (grunt.file.expand(name).length) {
    grunt.warn('Existing files may be overwritten!');
}
```

Comment: That's what I suspected, great to know. Thanks!